# Help with an article "A Realist's Diary: the book about money, relationships and the meaning of life"

Tags: grammar, articles, titles

I've asked a different question previously and got very helpful replies for the first part of the title, i.e. "A Realist's Diary". Now I'd like to know your opinion about the second part:

A Realist's Diary: **the** book about money, relationships and the meaning of life

Can we omit the definite article before "book"? It will look on the cover like this

A Realist's Diary
book about money, relationships and the meaning of life

I think it looks strange and grammatically it can't be correct. But English is my third language.
What do you think?

Comment: Perhaps you're concerned about how arrogant '**_the_** book about ...' sounds, and perhaps you'd be right. But your alternative doesn't work. Titles don't need to be sentences though; << “A Realist's Diary: Money, Relationships and the Meaning of Life” >> is fine (if not of a Shakespearian style standard).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm asking this question on behalf of a person that doesn't know English. They want it to be titled without the definite article because "there are two definite articles". In your version of the title (which I prefer myself too) do we need to capitalize each word in the second part of the title?

Comment: Two definite articles is rarely a problem. 'The Lord of the Rings' and 'The Taming of the Shrew' should put that notion to bed. It's the implication ('the book of cookery': very pretentious. 'The Book of Common Prayer': fair enough.) // Capitalisation in titles is largely a style issue. Use a style guide, or Writing.SE etc.

Comment: As Edwin says, the cover would typically just say "Money, relationships and the meaning of life". The fact that it's a book is immediately apparent simply by looking at it. Obviosly it's not a painting or a sculpture or a symphony. Expressly pointing that out to the reader is rather weird and maybe even condescending. Letting them know that the book is a book is like letting them know that the title is a title. "A Realist's Diary: The Title Of The Book About Money, Relationships And The Meaning Of Life".

Comment: @RegDwigнt that's hilarious! Thanks a lot guys! You know we who study English as a foreign language can pick up a lot of subtleties, but some things are very hard to grasp. For example in the native language of the discussed book mentioning the word "book" is fine. Maybe we have another tradition here. By the way, it's also apparent that it's a book because it's a DIARY, so